# R: how to extract r squared from lmekin in coxme package

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I'm trying to find out how well my mixed model with family effect fits the data. Is it possible to extract r squared values from lmekin functions? And if so, is it possible to extract partial r squared values for each of the covariables? 
Example:

```
model= lmekin(formula = height ~ score + sex + age + (1 | IID), data = phenotype_df, varlist = kinship_matrix)
```

I have tried the MuMin package but it doesn't seem to work with lmekin models. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use the `r.squaredLR()` function,

```
library(coxme)
library(MuMIn)
data(ergoStool, package="nlme")  # use a data set from nlme 
fit1 <- lmekin(effort ~ Type + (1|Subject), data=ergoStool)
r.squaredLR(fit1)
```

*(I am pretty sure that works, but one thing that is great to do is to create a reproducible example so I can run your code to double check, for example I am not exactly sure what `phenotype_df` looks like, and I am not able to run your code as it is, a great resource for this is the [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) package).*

Comment: Lucy - that is perfect! 

Sorry for the lack of reproducible example. I'll definitely check the reprex package. In my particular case I'm not so much interested in partial r squared for each covariate as I am interested in seeing how much a genetic variable improves the model - I think the best way to do this will be to run

    r.squaredLR(fit1)
 
before and after adding the genetic variable.